# MouseEvent movementX property apparently not supported in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, mouseevent

I am developing an application that needs to be compatible on IE 9 and above. I am using the movementX property on a MouseEvent object, however this same MouseEvent object does not have the movementX property in Internet Explorer (9 or 11).

I ran through Microsoft's documentation and indeed they claim to support this property on their MouseEvent objects. I have verified this is in fact a MouseEvent object, and it simply doesn't have the property. All the other properties appear to be available except this one.

Does anyone have experience with this issue? The internet at large looks pretty silent on this one.

Comment: see http://www.bing.com/search?q=mouseevent+movementx ... perhaps you have misread MSN as MSDN? If you type MouseEvent.prototype in the dev tool console it will list its members.

Comment: apologies... this MSDN ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974344(v=vs.85).aspx says Returns the difference in horizontal position (in screenX units) since the last mousemove (or pointermove) event.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem. It seems movementX and movementY on MouseEvent in IE11 just up and disappeared. I reverted my project back to a version I know worked in IE11 using these properties, and even that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please see Rob Parsons response. I ended up calculating movementX directly by taking the difference between screenX values.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to replicate it's behaviour by taking the delta between subsequent `screenX` and `screenY` values.

```
// Store previous screenX/screenY somewhere outside of callback
var prevX = 0;
var prevY = 0;

// Callback whenever the mouse moves
function mousemove(e) {
    var movementX = (prevX ? e.screenX - prevX : 0)
    var movementY = (prevY ? e.screenY - prevY : 0)

    prevX = e.screenX;
    prevY = e.screenY;
}
```

Note that if you are listening to `mousemove` to say, figure out if something is being dragged, you should reset `prevX` and `prevY` to 0 on `mouseup` or else you'll get the old screen values!