# event.movementX is not working in IE11 if i use mousemove event inside mousedown event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code I am trying to pass the mouse coordinates for column resizing. It is working in chrome, but not in IE11, event.movementX is always undefined in IE11, can anyone suggest the solution for this:

```
private mouseDown(): void {
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUp);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMove, true);
}

private mouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (this.props.resizing) {
        this.props.resizing(this.props.index, event.movementX);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide source code in order we can help you. For full guidance on how to write a good question please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @GuillaumeRAYMOND source code provided

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MouseEvent movementX property apparently not supported in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774726/mouseevent-movementx-property-apparently-not-supported-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: @GuillaumeRAYMOND no , because event object itself getting as empty

Comment: if event is empty you might have an other problem too.

Comment: What are the version of reactjs and TypeScript in use ?

Comment: react - 16.12.0 and typescript - 3.7.4

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample code working with Chrome? I mean only a simple demo of your behavior ideally using http://jsbin.com/.

Comment: I added my answer proposal here : https://jsbin.com/kexuzuc/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MouseEvent.movementX is not supported by IE11 you need to handle it in an old fashion way like in the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="log">Move your mouse around.</p>
</body>
<script>
    function logMovement(event) {
      if(event.movementX){
          //works with Chrome 79
          log.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', 'movement: ${event.movementX}, ${event.movementY}<br>'); 
      }else{
          //works with IE11 
          log.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', 'screen: ' + event.screenX +',' + event.screenY + '<br>'); 
      } 
    }

    const log = document.getElementById('log');
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', logMovement);
</script>
</html>
```

This code sample was tested on IE11 and Chrome 79 you can play with it in jsbin here: https://jsbin.com/kexuzuc/edit. Also note that syntaxic element like ${var} and many other feature are not supported by IE11.